# unrecognized selector sent to instance when trying to get property value

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

The error is the same in many question posted here already, but i guess the cause is different.

I have 3 classes: `MapView.m` that display the map and its plotted pins. `Pins.m` that mange all the pins data, and `PinsCalloutAnnotationView.m` which extends from `MKAnnotationView` and manage the callout of the annotation.

My issue is in this class, `PinsCalloutAnnotationView.m`:

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier  {

    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        if (((Pins*)annotation).isHootPin) {
            [self updateHootPin:t.hoot];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When i try to read the property `isHootPin`, the app crash and i get this stack:

```
[PinsCalloutAnnotationView isHootPin]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x203312d0
```

The property is pretty synthesized in `Pins` class:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite)BOOL isHootPin;
```

and

```
@synthesize isHootPin;
```

and i have set its value when i created it in `MapView.m`

```
pin.isHootPin=YES;
```

Is there any thing going wrong with that? Thanx in advance.

**EDIT:**

The class where `initWithAnnotation` method is called is `MapView`.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapV viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView;

    if ([annotation isMemberOfClass:[Pins class]]) {

        if (((Pins *)annotation).isHootPin) {
            NSString * annotationId = @"hootpin";
            annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationId];

            if (!annotationView) {
                annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationId];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, before call `initWithAnnotation`, i make a test, wether it has a property `isHootPin` set to yes, if so i call `initWithAnnotation`. And even in `initWithAnnotation`, i need to make sure if the annotation `isHootPin` is yes or not. If yes, i do a specific layout configuration for the annotation. So:

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier  {

    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        if (((Pins*)annotation).isHootPin) {//Try to check, but get crash and exception
            [self updateHootPin:t.hoot];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you call initWithAnnotation?

Comment: Hi Anna, i edited my post, please take a look. Is there anything else you need to know about?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear.  Please show where you create an instance of PinsCalloutAnnotationView and call initWithAnnotation on that instance (maybe in viewForAnnotation?).  It looks like the wrong object is being passed to initWithAnnotation.

Comment: Hi again, i edited my post with further details, please check :) Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure that the crash is happening on that line in PinsCalloutAnnotationView.m?  In viewForAnnotation, you have `annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]...` which doesn't create your custom class `PinsCalloutAnnotationView`.